# Installing testNG in not showing in run or giving errors, finalized solution

Tags: eclipse, selenium, eclipse-plugin, testng, testng-eclipse

if u have any of the below problems:
1.testng not showing in run configurations
2.testng now showing in Window/Show View
3.testng not showing in creating a new class
4.receiving this error
org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.addListener(Lorg/testng/ISuiteListener;)
5.receiving this error
noclassdeffounderror com/google/inject/stage

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

1. update java
2. update eclipse
3. got to https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse#install-snapshot (updates on testng problems)
4. scroll down till u find the zip version of the latest testng posted and download it
5. download and extract the updated testng zip file
6. add the jars u will find to the build path.

```
If u dont know how -> 

    A. right click on ur project
    B. properties
    C. java build path 
    D. make sure u r on the libraries tab
    E. add external jars 
    F. then go the file u unzipped and add any java file u find
```

7. after installing all these jars u may/ may not find testng as an option for execution
8. if u didnot find it , go to marketplace(Help/Eclipse marketPlace) search for testng and install it it may show that some files are already there or will be skipped just press ok
9. after installing the testng from marketplace restart ur eclipse
10. make sure u import "org.testng.annotations.Test"
    after adding "@test" before ur method declaration

for error num5: it is just a remaining jar called guince you can download it from (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.3/) or go to maven repository and search for com/google/inject/guice